# Why do the NEST ElasticClient did not find a document?

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest, elasticsearch.net

When I use Kibana to execute the following Searchrequest to Elasticsearch

```
GET _search
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "PDB_W2237.docx", 
      "default_operator": "AND"
    }
  }
}
```

it returns:

```
{
  "took": 14,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 15,
    "successful": 15,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 1,
    "max_score": 6.3527603,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "proconact",
        "_type": "proconact",
        "_id": "68cecf2c-7e5a-11e5-80fa-000c29bd9450",
        "_score": 6.3527603,
        "_source": {
          "Id": "68cecf2c-7e5a-11e5-80fa-000c29bd9450",
          "ActivityId": "1bad9115-7e5a-11e5-80fa-000c29bd9450",
          "ProjectId": "08938a1d-2429-11e5-80f9-000c29bd9450",
          "Filename": "PDB_W2237.docx"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

When I use the NEST ElasticClient like

```
var client = new ElasticClient();
var searchResponse = client.Search<Hit>(new SearchRequest {          
    Query = new QueryStringQuery {
         Query = "DB_W2237.docx",
         DefaultOperator = Operator.And
    }
});
```

it do return 0 Hits.

Here is the Indexmapping for the 4 Fields in the Hit:

```
{
  "proconact": {
    "mappings": {
      "proconact": {
        "properties": {
          "ActivityId": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "Filename": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "Id": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "ProjectId": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Are the two search-requests not the same?

Comment: Can you share your index mapping?

Comment: @TechnocratSid: I have added the index mapping for the 4 fields in the hit to the question.

Comment: Looking at your C# code there seems to be a lot of missing info, where is your ES connection specification? What is Hit and where is it's specification?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your mapping doesn't allow a token different than whatever is present in your index.

In your kibana query:

```
GET _search
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "PDB_W2237.docx", 
      "default_operator": "AND"
    }
  }
}
```

You're querying **PDB_W2237.docx** but in your NEST you're querying **DB_W2237.docx**.

If you want to query **DB_W2237.docx** and expecting results then you might have to change the analyzer from standard analyzer which is applied by default to something else [a possible candidate depends on your usecase](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-edgengram-tokenizer.html#_example_configuration_10).